# Effective way to generate low frequency square wave

Tags: oscillator, clock, 555

My goal is to generate a 40Hz square wave in a reasonably cheap and effective manner with a precision around 1%.

I considered two approaches:

- 555 chip: There it seems that they are themselves around 1% accurate and found it really hard to get reasonably accurate capacitors that do not cost a fortune.
- Oscillator: They all seem very high frequency and I couldn't find ones that could easily be divided to ~40Hz without needing a crazy chain of logic IC.
- 555 chip (2): with a variable capacitor and manually calibrating it with a scope. Aside from the tediousness of the procedure it also seem that variable capacitor are quite expensive and also have very low values.
- 555 chip (3): With a potentiometer and hand calibration.

Am I missing an easy solution there?

Comment: Microcontroller with a crystal oscillator.

Comment: why not adjust the R instead of the C? seems like pots are a lot cheaper and more available than tuners. or like stated, "just throw a mirco at it".

Comment: Good point @dandavis, they seem much cheaper!

Comment: @ThePhoton Wouldn't that require some way to store the code for the micro-controller + the time spend flashing it ? It seemed to me even more tedious than calibrating a variable capacitor/resistor

Comment: i micro would drift a lot less over time/temp than a tuned RC. flashing a micro can be done in under 30 seconds. a micro would also have a lot fewer connections to make, which take time apart from calibration.

Comment: Do you want one of these or ten thousand?

Comment: about 10-20 @gbarry

Comment: Program an Arduino to do it. Fairly trivial program, should only cost a couple of dollars and accurate to about 0.1%.

Comment: Thanks everyone! I thought about arduino but I originally couldn't find anything below 10$. In the end I found something cheap that will do!

Comment: @DARK_DUCK You are mixing up your metaphors, so to speak. Accuracy and precision are not the same thing. But as The Photon pointed out right away, your better bet is an MCU with a crystal. You solve both of the problems at once that way. +/- 100 ppm crystals are common and that covers their initial accuracy and drift over operating temperature for some given range. 1% is 10000 ppm. So you'd be fine with a crystal and an MCU (which adds its own issues but still should be okay.) You can get MCUs for under $1 that will get you there. That plus a crystal, anyway.

Comment: What is "cheap"? What is "effective"? What really are your constraints? Are you making one of those, or a thousand? Will this go on a custom PCB, or do you just want it on a breadboard? How much volume you can afford? Etc. - you can't just say "make it best". There's no single "best" way. It depends *heavily* on the needs of the product/application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One problem with RC oscillators, that concerns you here, is drift with age. It may be possible to find components that will drift slowly enough to stay within 1% of their rated value for a few years, but it's not a trivial task to find them. You won't be able to use an electrolytic capacitor as a timing element, for example, since it will dry out with age, changing its capacitance. Sometimes that's not a big issue (i.e. power supply decoupling), but for this application, that's a problem. So you'll have to stick with something like polyester or ceramic.

Changes in temperature may be the the biggest hurdle to overcome. I think  it's reasonable to expect a change in frequency of well over 1% over a temperature range of 0°C to 40°C.

To obtain 40Hz with a 555, the main timing capacitor will need to be of the order of 100nF, to be able to use reasonable values for the resistors (in the tens of kilohms). One consequence of this is that the trimmer capacitor you place in parallel with it will have to be roughly 1% of that value, and you may have trouble finding that.

Therefore, calibrate using a variable resistor, not a variable capacitance. You can find trim-pots of any value quite easily.

How square do you want this signal? A 555 can't easily produce a square wave. The output of a 555, in the standard astable configuration, is rectangular at best. It will not have 50% duty cycle. You can modify the configuration with a diode to produce something quite close to 50%, but I've struggled in the past with this dilemma. You can solve that particular problem by producing 80Hz, and dividing by two using a counter or flip-flop IC, like a 74HC74.

If you want precision, you need a crystal oscillator, which you can build easily with a crystal, a couple of inverters and a couple of tiny capacitors. Unfortunately you will also need a clock divider IC, since the oscillator will be at least several kilohertz.

These days I almost always go the microcontroller route, using something like an [ATTiny](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-2586-AVR-8-bit-Microcontroller-ATtiny25-ATtiny45-ATtiny85_Datasheet.pdf). This IC has a built-in RC oscillator, but it's heavily temperature and power-supply dependent, like your DIY version. For 1% accuracy, regardless of power supply voltage and temperature, crystal seems to be the way to go, which you can use with microcontrollers.

With a microcontroller, you need only two external capacitors and the crystal. The result will be a stable clock well within 1% of its rated value. The microcontroller will have the resources to divide by any factor you choose, to obtain 40Hz. The output can be perfectly square, too. All of this configuration is done in software.

If you still require some means of calibration, it's trivial to connect an external trimmer potentiometer to the microcontroller's ADC, and in software read its value and adjust the frequency accordingly. This way, you avoid having to write software unique to each production unit.

Lastly, using a microcontroller permits you to do anything you like to the signal, such as start the oscillator 500ms after power-on, or stop it if some input goes low, without the need for additional specialised hardware to implement these things.

Microcontrollers are cheap, predictable and flexible. RC oscillators are cheap, unpredictable and inflexible. I think this is a no-brainer. Your investment is time, and a programming setup, but the rewards are always worth it.

Comment: Thanks! I managed to order a batch of ATTiny already installed on PCBs. Thank you for the head's up about the inaccuracy of their internal clocks, I'll try calibrating with a potentiometer and if it's too temperature dependent I'll go with crystals eventually

Answer (score 4):

Depending on what you consider "complex", one cheap way would be to use CD4000 family to build a 32.768kHz quartz oscillator followed by a 5/4096 divider.

One way is to use five (5) DIP chips: the oscillator - CD4011B (quad NAND), the 10/4096 divider - a cascade of three CD4089B, the final divider - CD4013B.

Pricing current as of 2022-06-09, "qty 1":

- (1) CD4011BE   - TI $0.431
- (3) CD4089BE   - TI $1.491
- (1) CD4013BE   - TI $0.431
- (1) 32.768kHz quartz 32.768K12.5P2/DT38 - DigiKey $0.11
- Discrete capacitors/resistors - let's say $2.

Total part cost excluding shipping and pcb/protoboard: <$5. Less in higher quantities. Maximum frequency error is within +/-50ppm including aging and any reasonable operating temperature, for the quartz indicated. The supply voltage can be unregulated, and anything from 3V to 15V max will be fine.

One benefit of the DIP CD4000 family is that you're not competing with high volume mobile and automotive manufacturers, and there are reliable secondary market sources - so it's unlikely that the parts with vanish overnight. Microcontrollers these days are only available if you can actually place the order and get a firm delivery date. If you look at the inventory on Monday, make a design, then order the part on Friday, you may well have to wait a year to get it. We live in, ah, "interesting times".

Comment: Why use five DIP chips if only two will do?

Comment: @Uwe There's no "simple best solution" here. I have presented one. There are many others. It all depends on what's available. For example, the 32kHz solution has fairly limited EMI spectrum, and consumes negligible power. Maybe it matters, maybe it doesn't, but it's a working solution nevertheless. Plus, I really want to expose people to the pulse multiplier CD4089 - it's a chip that doesn't see much use, yet it's the low integration level equivalent of analog computing building blocks. A super-flexible device.

Answer (score 3):

The cheapest is any RC oscillator (the 555 is probably the worst solution for this though) that you manually tune with a potentiometer. Cost should be far below 1€. Temperature stability will be on the order of 100ppm/K giving you a 100K window for 1% stability. Just make sure that the cap is NP0/CG0 and make the resistors accordingly large.

If manual tuning isn't an option, the next best thing is an oscillator from which you derive 40 Hz either with flip-flops/counters or a tiny microcontroller (the other answers provide excellent explanations).

Answer (score 2):

If the solution must not involve software, I would probably combine these 3 chips:

1. 74HC4060 is a binary counter with crystal oscillator. Let it run with cheap 4.096 MHz crystal. Use the div 512 output providing 8 kHz.
2. CD4518 is a dual 4 bit BCD counter. Build a chain of 2 divide by 5 counters by using Q2 as output. This provides 320 Hz.
3. Finally you need a 3 bit binary (e.g. CD4040) counter to get 40 Hz.

It is also possible to build a div 100 with the 4518 and use a single final flipflop as last stage.

If you don't need 50% duty cycle, you can directly use the 4518 output and take the div 1024 from the 4060. In this case the 3rd chip is not needed.

The cost is somewhere between $2 and $3

Comment: It may be done easier. First divide 4.096 MHz by 100 and then by 1024. Duty cycle is 50 % when the divison by a power of two is the last one. A division by 512, then by 100 and at last by 2 is also possible.

Comment: The CD4518 is a dual 4 bit BCD counter. But this chip divides only by 10, not by 2 and 5. The CD74HC390 is the one to use for division by 5. "Two BCD decade or bi-quinary counters. One package can be configured to divide-by-2, 4,
5, 10, 20, 25, 50, 100"

Comment: Another combination. A 3.2768 MHz crystal, divide by 8192 using the 74HC4060, then by 5 and by 2 using 1/2 of a CD74HC390.

Comment: @Uwe: 4518 divides by 5 using Q2. Q3 and Q4 both divide by 10 with different duty cycles. And 4.096 MHz directly divided by 100 would need an extra oscillator gate, so no advantage. Your last post is better :)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a crazy chain of logic IC if you use a good combination of very few ICs.

It may be done using only a 74HC4060 as proposed by Jens and a 74HC390 and a crystal. Only two logic ICs, not more.

Several crystal frequencies are possible.

- A 3.2768 MHz crystal, divison by 8192 using the 74HC4060 and by 10 using the 74HC390.
- A 4.096 MHz crystal, divison by 1024 using the 74HC4060 and by 100 using the 74HC390.
- A 16.384 MHz crystal, divison by 4096 using the 74HC4060 and by 100 using the 74HC390.

The 74HC4060 is a crystal oscillator combined with a 14 stage binary counter. The crystal frequency may be divided by any power of 2 between 2 and 16384.

The 74HC390 has two decimal counters that may divide by 2, 5, 10, 20, 25, 50 and 100. If the last division is by 2, the duty cycle is 50 %.

If available also a 2.048 MHz or a 8.192 MHz crystal may be used.